# Creating a new project in Google Cloud using python without service account credentials

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-python

I am aiming to do a pythonic automated Google Cloud project manager. Just testing a bunch of models of Tensorflow and stuff. Even when I can fully access training, deploying and testing models inside a project, I can't mke any new projects since I am authenticated  with a service account through:

```
google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("thisisakey.json")
```

But as far as I understand, services account are project-binded so it's perfectly correct that creating a new project with it raises an error. In fact it does:

```
googleapiclient.discovery.build("cloudresourcemanager", "v1", cache_discovery=False)
```

Falis with:

```
Service accounts cannot create project without a parent.
```

So either creating/finding a "parent" for this project or log in a more "powerful" account could solve this. But I can't figure them out. Are there any other credential types to download and embed into python? Can I create a project from python? Everything I've checked about this is at least 2 years old and seems to be very outdated (back then projects were just not possible to create via APIs)

**Update:**
I've tried creating a project using the "parent" flag on the project's body, on the Organization made from the corp I work on. and even when this service account has "Owner" and "Organization Administrator" roles the create requests fails with:

```
 Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "forbidden"
 User is not authorized.
```

So the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign privileges to Service Accounts to do just about anything in Google Cloud. You have hit one of just a few that you cannot.

The problem is that your project is not part of an `Organization` (you have no parent). Your solution is to either setup Organizations or create your projects via the Google Cloud Console. Note: I do not recommend creating projects via software. You also need to setup billing in order to do anything useful.

There are two types of credentials with Google Cloud: User Credentials and Service Account Credentials. You cannot embed User Account Credentials into an application. User Account Credentials are created interactively as part of a login / authentication process using OAuth 2.0.

There are other types of access to cloud services such as API Keys, but these do not apply to your issue.

[Quickstart Using Organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations)

Comment: Thanks a lot, if then I setup an organization, activate the APIs via gcloud shell, and set up the billing as in: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudbilling/v1/python/latest/cloudbilling_v1.projects.html should it work?

Comment: Yes, except that once you enable orginanizations, there more more sets of permissions that you need at the `org` level.